# Concentric Circular Loops

Tags: magnetic-fields

We have two concentric circular wire loops. The inner loop has a stable, clockwise current. The outer loop does not have current. If the current of the inner loop increases, what is the direction of the current of the outer loop?

My first thought was "counter-clockwise" using the RHR, increasing flux, and so on. But after thinking a little more, I was wondering if the answer is "cannot be determined". I imagined the inner loop being very very small compared to the outer loop. In that case, the space between the outer and the inner loop would see an increase in B-field out of the page, and since that part has a much bigger area than the inner loop, it would have a bigger flux. The resulting current would be "clockwise" to counter that change. Is my logic in this case correct?

Comment: Your problem statement is inconsistent. You second sentence states that "the outer loop does not have a current."  I think this should be *The inner loop has a stable, clockwise current applied. The outer loop does not have an applied current.*

Comment: Since the inner loop's current is not changing initially, the outer loop has no current. That's how the problem statement was given to me

Comment: Sorry. It has been too long since I studied physics. The current in the inner loop creates a magnetic field. But a constant magnetic field will not induce a current in the outer loop. // So a DC current in a coil of wire creates an electromagnet. If you have a coil of wire and move a magnet in and out of the coil you can create an AC voltage in the coil.  // So back to the original problem, the magnetic field of the inner loop has to be changing to induce a current in the outer loop. //  freecharly has given the correct solution.

Comment: Yes the area in between the outer and inner loop will be large, but the magnitude of the magnetic field inside the inner loop will more than compensate. (1) magnetic fields near a loop are large, and (2) the points inside the inner loop are receiving nearly-aligned magnetic fields from a lot of points nearby.

Answer (score 2):

According to Lenz's Law, the current induced in the outer loop by an increase of the clockwise current in the inner loop has to flow counterclockwise. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law.

Comment: That was my first solution. But I don't think you got my point above.

Comment: @ItM - Your reasoning with the very small loop and the large area with "out-of-page" B-field is incorrect. The flux in the area between the outer loop and the inner loop must definitely be smaller than the "into-the-page" flux flowing through the area of the small loop because part of the field lines coming from this latter total flux stray out around the outer loop so that the total net flux through the outer loop is always "into-the-page".

Comment: Using Lenz's law the orientation of the induced current in the outer loop can be very easily obtained without any cumbersome flux integration over the large loop area. You only need to ask in which direction an induced current has to flow in the outer loop to produce a magnetic field that opposes the increasing magnetic field in the small loop. And this is only a current that flows counterclockwise.

Comment: your comment above "your reasoning..." is what I was looking for. If the outer loop was infinite, then indeed we would have a 0 net flux through the outer loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes the area in between the outer and inner loop will be large, but the magnitude of the magnetic field inside the inner loop will more than compensate. (1) magnetic fields near a wire are larger than at points farther away from the wire, and (2) the points inside the inner loop are receiving nearly-aligned magnetic fields from a lot of points nearby. That's a qualitative explanation.